# get all elements from list of lists in rows of 5

Tags: python

so say I have a list of lists

```
x = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '0', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', ' ', '#']]
```

Say I need to split this into 3 rows of strings, how do i do this?

Here is how I can do it BUT it is not scalable, say i had tons more lists, then I would have to write so many print statments. I thought about a for statment

```
print "".join(mlist[0])
print "".join(mlist[1])
print "".join(mlist[2])
```

I was thinking about something like this but it didn't work

```
zert = ""
total = 0
for a in mlist:
     for b in a:
        if total < 6:
            print zert
            total = 0
            zert = ''
        zert += b

        total += 1
```

^ the problem above is that i would need to save a first, then iterate over it BUT just checking if there is not an inbuilt function? I tried ''.join(mlist) but that does work since its lists in a list?

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You want each inner list on a line, rather than specifically 3?

Comment: yes i do @doctorlove as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to join lists:

```
print '\n'.join([''.join(inner) for inner in mlist])
```

The list comprehension creates a string of each nested list, then we join that new list of rows into a larger string with newlines.

Demo:

```
>>> mlist = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '0', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', ' ', '#']]
>>> print '\n'.join([''.join(inner) for inner in mlist])
#####
#0  #
### #
```

You could also have used a `for` loop:

```
for inner in mlist:
    print ''.join(inner)
```

Comment: I think you can use a generator expression here, can't you? `'\n'.join(''.join(inner) for inner in mlist)`

Comment: @poorsod: Yes, but that is slower than using a list comprehension. See [list comprehension without \[ \], Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9060653)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the link! Is `join` the only case where the list comp is faster than the generator exp?

Comment: @poorsod: `str.join()` is a specific case where using a list comp is better, because `str.join()` **has** to use a list internally (it iterates over the strings twice, once to calculate the output length, and a second time to build the string).

Comment: @poorsod: In most cases, avoiding having to build a list is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> orig_list = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', '0', ' ', ' ', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', ' ', '#']]
>>> new_list = [ "".join(x) for x in orig_list ]
>>> new_list
['#####', '#0  #', '### #']
>>> print("\n".join(new_list))
#####
#0  #
### #
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with what you have so far, to just directly print it.

```
for a in mlist:
  print "".join(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

or most simply

```
for a in x:
    print "".join(a)
```